# How to use select_related() when some rows return null values for that related-object?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I want to fetch two related objects from **groups** (**memberships** and **requests**), but with the query i'm using, **memberships** or **requests** could be empty and django does not allow me to do that.
The query:

```py
member = Member.objects.get(id=12345)
Group.objects.annotate(membership=FilteredRelation('members', condition=Q(members__member=member))) \
    .annotate(request=FilteredRelation('requests', condition=(requests__member=member))) \
    .filter(Q(membership__isnull=False) | Q(request__isnull=False)) \
    .select_related('membership', 'request')
```

with the models

```
class GroupMembership(models.Model):
    group = models.ForeignKey('group.Group', related_name='members', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    member = models.ForeignKey(
        'group.Member',
        related_name='group_membership',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )

class GroupMembershipRequest(models.Model):
    group = models.ForeignKey('group.Group', related_name='requests',  on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    member = models.ForeignKey(
        'group.Member',
        related_name='group_membership_request',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
```

But i'm getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
  File "/Users/Project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1186, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "/Users/Project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 66, in __iter__
    rel_populator.populate(row, obj)
  File "/Users/Project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1830, in populate
    self.local_setter(from_obj, obj)
  File "/Users/Project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 869, in local_setter
    f.remote_field.set_cached_value(from_obj, obj)
  File "/Users/Project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/mixins.py", line 23, in set_cached_value
    instance._state.fields_cache[self.get_cache_name()] = value
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_state'
```

probably caused by the nature of the query (some **membership** or **request** can be null).

Is there another way to achieve that with a single query, fetching the **membership** and **request**, even if they`re *Null*?

Comment: Shown code has zero references to `_state` attribute. Please show full error traceback.

Comment: Sorry, i didn't put it because it's django's internal attribute. I edited it and it's there now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
gm = GroupMembership.objects.filter(member=member,).values_list('group_id', flat=True)
gmr = GroupMembershipRequest.objects.filter(member=member,).values_list('group_id', flat=True)

g_ids = gm+gmr

Groups.objects.filter(id__in=g_ids,)
```

or you can try something like

```
gm = GroupMembership.objects.filter(member=member, group_id=OuterRef('pk'), )
gmr = GroupMembershipRequest.objects.filter(member=member,group_id=OuterRef('pk'), )

Groups.objects.annotate(is_member=Exists(gm), has_requested=Exists(gmr),)
     .filter(Q(is_member=True)|Q(has_requested=True),)
```